# PHP get HTML tag with text to display on nicEditor

Tags: php, mysql, nicedit

I have data (MySQL) with html tag which I want to display on `nicEditor`, but it alway errors :

> unterminated string literal

The following code breaks on the line `nicE.setContent(...`

Javascript code:

```
<script>
    var nicE = new nicEditors.findEditor('txtfulldes');
    nicE.setContent('<?php echo $datafrommysql?>');
</script>
```

Data is in MySQL

It has br, bold and more html tags

- and miscellaneous charges, as well as acceptance of interview without
- **any prerequisites by the interviewing company/party could be a scam.**
- It is also illegal for the interviewing company/party to detain the

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably text $datafrommysql have new lines like

```
something<br/>
something<br/> 
something
```

which break js.

it should be instead

```
something<br/>something<br/>something
```

in one line.

if that's the case and you have `<br/>` tags in it for new lines try clear `\r` and `\n`:

```
nicE.setContent('<?php echo str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array("", ""),$datafrommysql)?>');
```

Comment: but with that you can. it's just to get rid newline as `\n \r` did you try solution I wrote?